# Caching getJSON response that populates select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, caching

I am working on an application that is supposed to work offline using background sync. It's a patient registration web app. When you load the app, it makes a rest call using getJSON jquery method to get a list of locations from the server and populate a select box. But now when the application is offline, the REST call obviously fails and the select box appears empty with no content. And it's not possible to create a patient without selecting a location. I want to be able to cache the locations so that when the page is offline, it will load locations from the cache and populate the select box and users will be able to still register patients while offline. Here is my code that loads the locations from the database via REST

```
$.getJSON("/openmrs/ws/rest/v1/location", function(result) {
      var locations = $("#identifierLocations");

      $.each(result.results, function() {
        locations.append($("<option />").val(this.uuid).text(this.display));
      });
});
```

I'm not an everyday javascript programmer. I only use it when it's absolutely necessary so I very limited experience with this. I have looked at all the other questions that relate to caching ajax response but non of them seem to solve the problem I'm having.

Comment: Are you able to pass back an HTTP response code of 304 not modified the first time around, so that way the browser can still grab the cached payload even when offline? Or, try storing the payload in a cookie or session storage while you can reach the api online, then when it is offline, you can read the list from the cookie/session storage.

Comment: Browsers won't use cached data when the server is unreachable. You need to save the information locally in the application, and detect the error when you try to make the `$.getJSON` call and it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the json in session storage or local storage. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage